# Compare datasets in R

Tags: r, dataset, associations, compare, substitution

I have gathered a set of transactions in a CSV file of the format:

```
{Pierre, lait, oeuf, beurre, pain}
{Paul, mange du pain,jambon, lait}
{Jacques, oeuf, va chez la crémière, pain, voiture}
```

I plan to do a simple association rule analysis, but first I want to exclude items from each transactions which do not belong to `ReferenceSet = {lait, oeuf, beurre, pain}`.

Thus my resulting dataset would be, in my example :

```
{Pierre, lait, oeuf, beurre, pain}
{Paul,lait}
{Jacques, oeuf, pain,}
```

I'm sure this is quite simple, but would love to read suggestions/answers to help me a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Another answer references `%in%`, but in this case `intersect` is even handier (you may want to look at `match`, too -- but I think it's documented in the same place as `%in%`) -- with `lapply` and `intersect` we can make the answer into a one-liner:

Data:

```
> L <- list(pierre=c("lait","oeuf","beurre","pain") ,
+           paul=c("mange du pain", "jambon", "lait"),
+           jacques=c("oeuf","va chez la crémière", "pain", "voiture"))
> reference <- c("lait", "oeuf", "beurre", "pain")
```

Answer:

```
> lapply(L,intersect,reference)
$pierre
[1] "lait"   "oeuf"   "beurre" "pain"  

$paul
[1] "lait"

$jacques
[1] "oeuf" "pain"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ben, this methods sounds good and straightforward.Now I'll try to understand how to implement it so as to build the input list from a csv file, and so as to write the output of the lapply method into a file with a list as well. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

One way is follows (but, as I'm leaving the structure as a matrix I've left NAs where data has been removed (these could be removed if exporting back to CSV); I'm also sure it's possible to do it without loops - this would make it faster (but, IMHO less readable), and I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do the logic too - I'd also be interested in seeing someone's else view on this)

```
ref <- c("lait","oeuf","beurre","pain")
input <- read.csv("info.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE,strip.white=TRUE)

> input
   V1            V2                  V3     V4      V5
1  Pierre          lait                oeuf beurre    pain
2    Paul mange du pain              jambon   lait        
3 Jacques          oeuf va chez la crémière   pain voiture

input <- as.matrix(input)
output <- matrix(nrow=nrow(input),ncol=ncol(input))
currentRow <- c()

for(i in 1:nrow(input)) {
  j <- 2
  output[i,1]<-input[i,1]
  for(k in 2:length(input[i,])) {
    if(toString(input[i,k]) %in% ref){
      output[i,j] <- toString(input[i,k])
      j<-j+1
    }
  }
}

> output
     [,1]      [,2]   [,3]   [,4]     [,5]  
[1,] "Pierre"  "lait" "oeuf" "beurre" "pain"
[2,] "Paul"    "lait" NA     NA       NA    
[3,] "Jacques" "oeuf" "pain" NA       NA
```

Comment: In my late evening Sunday tiredness, I'd forgotten about the `*apply` functions - these are fairly straightforward and would cut the code down

Answer (score 1):

The `%in%` operator will come in handy.

```
pierre <- c("lait","oeuf","beurre","pain")  
paul <- c("mange du pain", "jambon", "lait")  
jacques <- c("oeuf","va chez la crémière", "pain", "voiture")

reference <- c("lait", "oeuf", "beurre", "pain")

pierre_fixed <- pierre[pierre %in% reference]
paul_fixed <- paul[paul %in% reference]
jacques_fixed <- jacques[jacques %in% reference]  

pierre_fixed 
paul_fixed
jacques_fixed
```

Comment: Thank you so much all of you, sounds interesting approach, going to try them.