# How to check if two data frames are equal

Tags: database, r, dataset, compare, dataframe

Say I have large datasets in R and I just want to know whether two of them they are the same. I use this often when I'm experimenting different algorithms to achieve the same result. For example, say we have the following datasets:

```
df1 <- data.frame(num = 1:5, let = letters[1:5])
df2 <- df1
df3 <- data.frame(num = c(1:5, NA), let = letters[1:6])
df4 <- df3
```

So this is what I do to compare them:

```
table(x == y, useNA = 'ifany')
```

Which works great when the datasets have no NAs:

```
> table(df1 == df2, useNA = 'ifany')
TRUE 
  10
```

But not so much when they have NAs:

```
> table(df3 == df4, useNA = 'ifany')
TRUE <NA> 
  11    1
```

In the example, it's easy to dismiss the `NA` as not a problem since we know that both dataframes *are* equal. The problem is that `NA == <anything>` yields `NA`, so whenever one of the datasets has an `NA`, it doesn't matter what the other one has on that same position, the result is always going to be `NA`.

So using `table()` to compare datasets doesn't seem ideal to me. **How can I better check if two data frames are identical?**

P.S.: Note this is not a duplicate of [R - comparing several datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567524/r-comparing-several-datasets), [Comparing 2 datasets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459138/comparing-2-datasets-in-r) or [Compare datasets in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872333/compare-datasets-in-r)

Comment: `identical(df1,df2)`

Comment: @Frank, I believe the solutions are common and the problems are roughly the same (let's not get into semantics about the difference between a matrix and a data frame). However, to help future searches, I believe both Qs should be kept. BTW, your link targets this same page, here's the URL to that other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767851/regarding-matrix-comparison-in-r

Comment: Oh, oops. Thanks for getting the right link. I don't think there's anything wrong with having dupes, but it might be better to link them together (if/when they actually are dupes), based on what I've browsed on meta and the blog. Just a thought.

Comment: @Frank, I agree wholeheartedly, but how can we link them without marking one as a dupe of the other?

Comment: Yeah, I meant that we could mark this as a dupe, just because it came later. You have an answer, so I figured you wouldn't mind. If you agree, you could flag it for closure as a dupe or I could start a vote. (None have been started.)

Comment: @Frank: all right, I'll do it. It's harakiri time!

Comment: `dplyr::all_equal()` has arguments for ignoring column and row order, and for converting classes from factor to character and integer to double.

Comment: `dplyr::all_equal()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Look up all.equal. It has some riders but it might work for you.

```
all.equal(df3,df4)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(df2,df1)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I just got to know this function and will further test it to see if it really works for this particular task, but so far, so good. Thanks!

Comment: It's important to note that if the items being compared are NOT equal, then `all.equal` will *not* return `FALSE`.    Instead, you have to use `isTRUE( all.equal(df2,df1) )` to get a `TRUE/FALSE` output from `all.equal`

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, you're right, but in that case I believe it is better to just go ahead and use `identical()`, as @Metrics suggested above. The thing about `all.equal()` is that returns a vector "describing the differences between target and current", which can be good or bad depending on what kind of output you're looking for.

Comment: `dplyr::all_equal()` is another option. By default it ignores column and row order, and is sensitive to variable classes, but those defaults can be overidden: `dplyr::all_equal(target, current, ignore_col_order = FALSE, ignore_row_order = FALSE, convert = TRUE)`

Comment: For my two big data frames and `identical(df2,df1)` returns `FALSE` but `isTRUE(all.equal(df2,df1))` returns `TRUE` (with `all_equal()` also). Any idea why ?

Answer (score 48):

As [Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1493368/metrics) pointed out, one could also use `identical()` to compare the datasets. The difference between this approach and that of [Codoremifa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19119398/1169233) is that `identical()` will just yield `TRUE` of `FALSE`, depending whether the objects being compared are identical or not, whereas `all.equal()` will either return `TRUE` or hints about the differences between the objects. For instance, consider the following:

```
> identical(df1, df3)
[1] FALSE

> all.equal(df1, df3)
[1] "Attributes: < Component 2: Numeric: lengths (5, 6) differ >"                                
[2] "Component 1: Numeric: lengths (5, 6) differ"                                                
[3] "Component 2: Lengths: 5, 6"                                                                 
[4] "Component 2: Attributes: < Component 2: Lengths (5, 6) differ (string compare on first 5) >"
[5] "Component 2: Lengths (5, 6) differ (string compare on first 5)"
```

Moreover, from what I've tested `identical()` seems to run much faster than `all.equal()`.