# Remove Non-Matching Dataframe Names Nested in A List

Tags: r

I have two lists consisting of dataframes - df_quintile and disease_df_quintile. I do not know how to represent them concisely, but this is how they look like in Rstudio:

[image]

[image]

Notice, disease_df_quintile consists of 5 dataframes (dataframes 1 through 5), while disease_df_quintile consists of 4 (dataframes 2 through 5). I would like to cross check both lists and remove any dataframes that are not shared by both lists - so in this case, I would like to remove the first dataframe from the df_quintile list. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can share sample data and expected output

Comment: I suggest looking into the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119320/how-to-check-if-two-data-frames-are-equal

Furthermore, you could use lapply to loop through the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independently of the content of the list, you can first find the repeated names and then subsetting the lists:

```
##-- Fake lists
l1 <- as.list(1:5)
names(l1) <- 1:5

l2 <- as.list(2:5)
names(l2) <- 2:5

##-- Common names and subsetting
common_names <- intersect(names(l1), names(l2))
l1 <- l1[common_names]
l2 <- l2[common_names]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match the list's names and keep the common ones.

```
keep <- match(names(disease_df_quintile), names(df_quintile))
new_df_quintile <- df_quintile[keep]
```